# How to check if a row exists in a specific position. VB.NET 2008 + msaccess 2003

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2003

I'm trying make a code for vb.net 2008 + msaccess 2003 to check if there is a row in a specific position between 2 rows, to be used on inserting data, which the previous data was deleted. (sorry for my bad english)

for example: there are data in rows 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. if i were to delete row 2 now, and add data later to that same position so that the position 2 wouldn't be blank. (because i use maxrow count for auto numbering)

refer to this statement:

```
If ds.Tables("MovieList").Rows(row) exist then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Simple answer is no because of the way all relational databases work. Once data is deleted the empty space in the data files are not reused until you do a compact / repair in ms access.
Databases like sequel server do this compaction or space recovery in the background while MS Access it must be done manually or set on a timer with vb code to perform the compact / repair.

However if you trying to recover a number in a auto increment field that was deleted; that is a different question all together.

If you are simply trying to organize a list of items there are much better ways to do so than using the auto increment field.

Maybe re-ask the question on how to sort items in a specific way.

Comment: Thank you! I'll send another question after I figure out another idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables("MovieList").Rows(row).Item(1)) Then
```